# How to change the drawable of radio button to custom icon and recover?

Tags: android, drawable, android-radiobutton

I met the problem when I try to use radio button in RecyclerView. It`s easy to change the drawable to a custom one. But as we know that the view in the RecycerView is recycled, if I changed the drawable to a custom one, when it is used again it should show as the default drawable. Since the radio button must be selectable again. So, if I want to accomplish this function, any good idea?

Here is the explanation:

```
private List<MotocareService> purchased = new LinkedList<>();

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(K holder, int position) {
    if (purchased.contains(item)) {   // line 5
        currentRadio.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.ic_check_black);   // line 6
        currentRadio.setEnabled(false);
    } else {
        // line 9: need to change the drawable back
        currentRadio.setEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

As shown above, at line 5, I want to judge whether MotocareService item is in the purchased list. If it is in the list, I have to change its drawable to R.drawable.ic_check_black and disable it. But since the view is recycled and it will be used again in another position. I have to handle another case -- the item not in the list. Also, the item must be selectable and enabled, so that the user can select the item.

Comment: put your code for better understanding

Comment: simple make a model class or arrayllist that will check if checkbox is checked or not. and onBindView checking that model class or arrayllist  to make checkbox is selected or not. It will work perfectly. And at time of recreating view by RecylerView than condition will check again and checkbox have correct value

Comment: @VishvaDave the explanation is added, so any good idea?

Comment: @ShouhengWang you need to take on boolean variable in your model class. and set it's value for every position true or false.

Comment: @VishvaDave thanks for your comment. But the real problem that confused   me is not how to record states of every RadioButton. It is the to change the drawable and recover. I am afraid that if the RadionButton is recycled, it may still use the custom drwable.

Comment: @ShouhengWang then in the else part change drawable to default and also set by default the default drawable

Comment: @VishvaDave That's the point. So do you have any good suggestions?